Roundtrip exr does not exactly match when saving as png
The result of saving a render as png vs saving as exr, loading back into blender, then saving as png is very slightly different.
output.exr

Render image
Use the Image->Save As menu to save the render as RGBA, 32-bit float (full), zip (lossless), follow scene for color management

output_from_exr.exr

Enable compositing nodes
Load output.exr as an image
Connect a viewer node
Change the image editor to use the viewer node
Use the Image->Save As menu to save the render as RGBA, 32-bit float (full), zip (lossless), follow scene for color management

The two images output.exr and output_from_exr.exr match 100% and are the same image.
output.png

Use the Image->Save As menu to save the render as RGBA, 8-bit, 15% compression, follow scene for color management

output_from_exr.png

Enable compositing nodes
Load output.exr as an image
Connect a viewer node
Change the image editor to use the viewer node
Use the Image->Save As menu to save the render as RGBA, 8-bit, 15% compression, follow scene for color management

The two images output.png and output_from_exr.png are very similar, but do not match 100% when using the tool idiff (part of the OpenImageIO: https://openimageio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/idiff.html).

Png and Exr are very different, from color depth to color space. But what's the question here?

I believe the same thing is also happening for exr (have been doing several tests with different setting, then got sidetracked). Essentially, if you render and save as a png vs render as exr, load the exr in blender, then save that as a png with the same settings, the resulting images are very slightly different (not human detectable).

As you said, "not human detectable" but nevertheless is a direct from render to png saving something else then importing some image (no matter which format) and saving this to png. So you are doing different things and get slightly different results. As @Emir put it, what exactly is your question here? For technical details where the differences lie you should probably contact the developers.

A pure guess, the anomalies might arise from the conversions between 16-bit integer and 32-bit float representations of 'identical' values. IMO, this question will find greater expertise on a stack such as Computer Graphics, than here on Blender. Rather than forcing a migration, this is an invitation to consider posting elsewhere?

Another possibility is differences introduced by repeatedly applying color management on the image
